# What is the Xcode 4 shortcut to move the cursor to the commit message

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

XCode 4's Commit interface is great.  However I am really [lazy](http://www.hhhh.org/wiml/virtues.html) and I want to commit without the use of a mouse.

`cmd-alt-c` brings up the commit dialogue.  However, when I type no text appears because the lower text box is not in focus.  How do I move the focus to the message dialogue using a shortcut key?

Comment: But it is not programming related question..

Comment: It's a question about the programming IDE and the 3rd of the four general types of questions to ask here is "software tools commonly used by programmers." This is the right place for the question.

Comment: Also, I wish I knew the answer, as it drives me nuts every time. Cmd-Opt-C to commit, then hand over to the mouse, find the cursor, click in the box, *then* type, and then use the mouse again to get out. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `shift + tab` twice moves the focus to the commit message.  So you can type the commit message.

However, I have found no shortcut to actually make the commit.

Comment: You can use Fn + Return to commit.

Comment: BTW, the Shift + Tab shortcut has become somewhat impractical in the current version of Xcode (4.3.2 as of writing), as you now have to press it five times...

Answer (score 0):

select the line then "cmd+/" check this out

Comment: Isn't this just to comment out a line?